# mkdir : invalid option -- 'R'

Tags: command-line, directory, mkdir

I wanted to run a bunch of `mkdir` commands to create folders:

```
mkdir -p mydir/animals/mammals/{platypus,bat,dog}
mkdir -p mydir/animals/reptiles/{snakes,crocodile,lizard}
mkdir -p mydir/colors/basic/{red,blue,green}
mkdir -p mydir/colors/blended/{yellow,orange,pink}
mkdir -p mydir/shape/{circle,square,cube}
```

While running these, I am getting the error

```
mkdir : invalid option -- 'R'
```

What is wrong here and how can I fix it?

Comment: Looks quite strange. Can you isolate the actual command causing the error by running each separately?

Comment: Are these the exact commands you are running? The only time that error should occur is if you have a letter 'R' after the p

Answer (score 1):

There are some possibilities.

1. `/usr/bin/mkdir` was replaced by another 'mkdir'.
2. `mkdir`was defined as alias.
3. `mkdir` was defined as bash function.

Please look it up on bash command line.

```
type mkdir
alias
```